# Как сделать отступ в CardView?? Как сделать тень и закругленные углы?

Tags: java, android, cardview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp">
```

Отступы слева и справа есть, также есть отступы между карточками в размере 40 dp(вверх одной карточки и низ другой карточки). А между первой карточкой и верхней части экрана и последней карточкой и нижней части экрана, размерность составляет 20dp.
Как сделать так, чтобы было равномерно?

Также интересует, как сделать тень и закругленные углы в CardView.

Comment: Проблемы с разметкой - приложите разметку. Две проблемы в одном вопросе вообще не уместны, а ответы на вторую часть находятся в описании класса, это его стандартная функциональнальность.

Answer (score 3):

Вот так:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_radius_corner"
        card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/card_elevation"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Отступ сверху и снизу**

Я так понял у вас все `CardView` находятся в контейнере, типа `ScrollView`? Или вы используете `RecyclerView`? Вообщем, в родительский `View` добавьте

```
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
```

**Закругленные углы**

```
card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
```

**Тень**

```
card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
```